# Issue on ASP.NET MVC Page on Azure: generic error on page showing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 WebApp deployed on Azure. On local server anything is working fine! But when I go on the page that should show databinded (on Azure server) a generic error is displayed!
I added in web.config file the connection string provided by the azure service:

.database.windows.net,1433;Database=;User ID=MarianoMovies@vjafequr73;Password=;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;">

but the problem persists.

I hope in some help. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: The connection string is:     <add name="SQLAzureConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:<MyServerName>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=Movies;User ID=MarianoMovies@vjafequr73;Password=<MyServerPassword>;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"></add>

Comment: do you have a try catch statement that logs the error?

Comment: Can you use the correct connection string that points to azure, and use your dev machine to inspect the error?

Comment: The connection string is correct, I found it on Azure page dadicated to SQL db manage. I don't have a try catch block in my code, but the page is visible on localhost.
I should try to use my dev machine to inspect the error, how should I do this? I should look on my personal Azure page to check the error?

Comment: Have you checked the connection string name on your azure portal? Go to the configure tab of your web app and make sure the connection string name under "connection strings" is the name of your connection string in your config file which is "SQLAzureConnection".

Comment: In the configure tab, under "connection strings" I have no connection string reported. Maybe I have to add one!

Comment: Have you linked your database to your webapp yet? You can go to the Linked Resources tab of your web app, add your database and that will automatically add the connection string for you. You just need to double check it has the correct name.

Comment: Yes, I've linked my DB to the app by Linked Resources, but nothing has changed. I've added more connection string to let the app use my local db and the db on Azure.